# jQuery with Ajax functions are stop working after inserting PHP codes

Tags: php, ajax

All my jQuery with Ajax functions are stop working after inserting following PHP codes,

```
 <?php
        //includes data base configuration file
        include_once "config.php";

        $order = "SELECT * FROM tblUser";

        $result = mysql_query($order);    

        if(!$result){
        //if result not success exit from script
        die("Error:".mysql_error());
        }
        //more codes here...
?>
```

Comment: you may have error in your php script.

Comment: @sam may be $result is null that's why it goes to die and terminate from there. try by echoing instead of die.

Comment: what is the result of the ajax call? You can use Chrome Dev Tools network tab to analyze XHR requests

Comment: you can turn php error reporting on - put `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your php code. This will echo you php error to the browser so you can see what is wrong.

Comment: You'd better provide your jQuery codes.
I can provide you procedure to deal with this kind of issues.
Make the most of firebug or IE developer tools or chrome developer tools to monitor network. - First you should ensure the http request has been sent. - Second have a look at the data responded by server.

Comment: The above codes is nothing to deal with my Ajax post request , I used this php script for display data in html table when page onload. The sql query is not return any error.Table data are displaying in the html table.  But I use save button to save the data to database by Ajax post,the save button is not working when I insert above code segment.

Comment: Thanks all, I found the issue, it is not working when the php codes are inside the form tag, I take out the codes and place below the form.It working now.

Comment: Mix database related codes with HTML is not a good habit. The PHP code should have nothing to with the form of HTML, PHP runs on server, HTML runs on browser. You'd better check whether the PHP code cause the whole script stopped.